# Booking 2 ways ticket, not onboard 1 way, consider canceling both?

Tags: singapore, vietnam

It's hard to explain the situation in title, so here it is:

I'm booking a 2 ways tickets from Singapore to Vietnam (Hanoi). However, i didn't board the trip Sing-Viet. Instead, I purchased another 1 way ticket, from Singapore to Vietnam with different time.

In that case, when I'm back from Vietnam to Singapore, the flight counter said, my tickets is not valid anymore, as i didn't take the 1st board,

> Based on International Rules, they said.

So, Is my 2 ways tickets valid?

Comment: Short answer: What the airline did is a common practice.  If you miss the first leg of a round-trip flight, or a multi-stop flight, the rest of your ticket is cancelled.  This was probably explained in the fine print of the "contract of carriage" when you bought your ticket.

Comment: If you really did this for a reasonable reason rather than to try and get round the airlines rules, you might try asking the airline very nicely to reinstate the ticket, and explain the circumstances. But for future reference these things go much better if you talk to the airline in advance.

Comment: Why are we flagging this as a duplicate of a duplicate? Is this the duplicate inception?

Comment: I changed the duplicate marker so that it's correct now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much the standard, and it prevents hidden city ticketing, among other things - most airlines apply the rule that if you don't take any leg - be it leg A, B, or C of any flight - any legs after that one will be cancelled, and you'll likely lose your money for them too.  It's almost certainly in your terms of carriage for the ticket.

At this point, your best bet is to read your specific airline's terms very closely to see if they mention this. If not, ask them about it, and if it does, well then you will have to ask them very nicely about it and explain why they should 'break' their rules to allow you the leg.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your answer, have looking through the whole terms and conditions, and no, they don't mention anything. Secondly, 2 days before 2nd leg, they still sent me a reminder email regarding "my flight" is about soon.

Comment: Did you take your alternative flight for the first leg on the same airline? In that case, you may be able to convince them to reactivate your ticket.